# Social Share of products in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, socialshare

​I have to create a functionality to share the products to social media sites like facebook, twitter, etc. This can be accomplished via front end i.e. Spartacus. Spartacus is a lean, Angular-based JavaScript storefront for SAP Commerce Cloud. But need to know can this be configured via Backend. Do I need to make any changes in the backend or will it be storefront changes only.

Comment: Where will you trigger start sharing? It look very complex and given information not enough. On next step they request to info about where the user start buying these products. So you need complete marketing solution at the end. Please create your user and product manager stories first.

Comment: @mkysoft Thank you for the information. But the selling will be done in our platform only. The customer can only share the products to social media sites like Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, etc. The same we can do in Amazon or Flipkart. Below the products you will find the share option. It will be only one way, one time activity.

Comment: You said that "customer" share the product. So you need to just at share on facebook button. Every social media platform their own way. For example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/
You can do that on storefront (spartacus or old jsp).